# How to call a function after mat-dialog closed in Angular 12

Tags: angular, mat-dialog

I have a component called `ListScheduleComponent` it has a function that opens a `mat-dialog` with `CreateScheduleComponent` view:

```
  handleDateSelect(selectInfo: DateSelectArg) {
    this.fileNameDialogRef = this.dialog.open(CreateScheduleComponent, {
      data: {
        startdate: this.datePipe.transform(selectInfo.start, 'yyyy-M-dd'),
        enddate: this.datePipe.transform(selectInfo.end, 'yyyy-M-dd'),
      },
    });
  }
```

and a function that loads all events:

```
getAllEvents(){
  //Events are loaded and displayed in the calendar
}
```

so it looks like this:

[image]

Now in my `CreateScheduleComponent` I have a submit function:

```
onSubmit(): void {
    this.calendarService
      .createNewEvent(this.eventForm.value)
      .subscribe((response) => {
        if (response.statuscode===201) {
          //Call getAllEvents();
        } else {
          console.log(response.message);
        }
      });
  }
```

I know how to close this dialog just by `this.dialogRef.close()` but my problem is, How can I call the getAllEvents(); function from `ListScheduleComponent` component after form `onSubmit()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subscribe afterClosed() method on dialog and do your stuff here which you want to do after dialog has been closed -

```
handleDateSelect(selectInfo: DateSelectArg) {
    this.fileNameDialogRef = this.dialog
      .open(CreateScheduleComponent, {
        data: {
          startdate: this.datePipe.transform(selectInfo.start, "yyyy-M-dd"),
          enddate: this.datePipe.transform(selectInfo.end, "yyyy-M-dd"),
        },
      })
      .afterClosed()
      .subscribe((res) => {
        // call getAllEvents() here
      });
  }
```

Comment: not working, can you provide an example with working solution?

Comment: @FaiZalDong it worked for me, can you share what you tried?